# The idea behind the time elapsed between two phase path points?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, vector-fields

Given $y'=3y$ an dynamical system. I'm asked to find the time elapsed between $y=5$ and $y=185$. As $$\int_{T_{a}}^{T{b}} dt$$ definition suggests, I've calculated $$\int_{5}^{185} dt = \int_{5}^{185} \frac{dy}{3y} = \frac{1}{3} (ln|185|-ln|5|)$$ However, the question continues with the part that asks calculation of the time elapsed between $y=-50$ and $y=600$. Similarly, as $$\int_{-50}^{600} dt = \int_{-50}^{600} \frac{dy}{3y} =  \frac{1}{3} (ln|600|-ln|-50|) = \frac{1}{3} (ln600-ln50)$$

Firstly, I wonder whether I made any mistake. I hardly grasp the notion of time elapsed between phase path points. The critical point here is $y=0$. Thus, the phase portrait is simply y-axis with $y=0$ as an unstable fixed point. What is the difference between these two calculations? Can you explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The integration interval on the time side is not the same as that on the $y$ side, $T_a\ne y(T_a)$ etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case you are right to be doubtful, as you can wait for all times, but starting at negative value will never lead to positive values.

Comment: So, is there any way to handle the second calculation? Or, this explanation would suffice. I clearly understand what you meant to say. However, is there any mathematical way -including the sketch of phase diagram- to make it concrete?

Comment: Just write down $y(t)=y(T_a)e^{3(t-T_a)}$ to see that a sign change is impossible.

Comment: Now, I got it, when we wrote down $y(t)= -50.e^{t+50}$, then there is no $t$ s.t $y(t)=600$. So, as you suggested starting from $-50$, there can be no $t$ to reach $600$.